# I am getting the error; "'navigation.navigate' is undefined " or navigation.navigate is not a method (react native)

Tags: javascript, react-native, navigation, expo

I am trying to do this as a beginner's project but I keep getting the error:
**navigation.navigate is not a function. (In 'navigation.navigate('Recipe')','navigation.navigate is undefined)**
I am just trying to navigate to a page when I click on the button, but I keep getting the error. I tried going through the docs and console logging 'navigation', but it just says undefined.

Here is my **app.js**:

```
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import Index from './src/screens/Index';
import AddData from './src/components/AddData'
import recipescreen from './src/components/RecipeScreen'

const navigator = createStackNavigator({

  Index: Index,
  Add: AddData,
  Recipe: recipescreen

},{
    initialRouteName: 'Index',
    title: 'RecipesHub'
});

export default createAppContainer(navigator);
```

and the **resultlist component:**

```
import React from "react";
import {
  View,
  Text,
  FlatList,
  StyleSheet,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Alert,
  Modal,
  Button,
} from "react-native";
import ResultsDetails from "../components/ResultsDetail";
import recipescreen from "../components/RecipeScreen";
import * as axios from "axios";

const ResultList = ({ title, recipes, hasError, navigation }) => {
  const deleteRecipe = async (id) => {
    const response = await fetch(
      "https://recipehub-291212.ew.r.appspot.com/rest/Recipeservice/deleterecipe/" +
        id,
      {
        method: "DELETE",
      }
    );
  };

  const createTwoButtonAlert = (param) =>
    Alert.alert(
      "You are going to delete this recipe",
      "Are you sure you want to delete?",
      [
        {
          text: "Cancel",
          onPress: () => {},
          style: "cancel",
        },
        { text: "OK", onPress: () => deleteRecipe(param.id) },
      ],
      { cancelable: false }
    );

  return (
    <View style={{ marginTop: 50 }}>
      <Text>{title} </Text>
      <Text>{hasError} </Text>
      <FlatList
        horizontal={true}
        data={recipes}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
        renderItem={({ item }) => {
          return (
            <TouchableOpacity onLongPress={() => createTwoButtonAlert(item)}>
              <View>
                <View>
                <ResultsDetails result={item} />
                </View>
                <View>
                  <Button title = "recipe page" onPress = {(navigation)=>navigation.navigate('Recipe')}/>
                </View>
              </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          );
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});

export default ResultList;
```

**But when I press on the button, it gives me the error.**

the **recipe page** is just a basic page with a view and a text:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Text, View, Button, StyleSheet} from 'react-native'
import recipes from './getRecipes';

class recipescreen extends React.Component{
render(){
    return(
    
        <View> 
        <Text>This is the recipe page</Text>
        </View>
    )
}
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

});

export default recipescreen;
```

Could someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems your ResultList component doesn't receive `navigation` prop. If `ResultList` is child component of screen (your screens are which you declared inside `createStackNavigator`) you should add this prop manually in screen component render `<ResultList navigation={navigation} ...otherProps />`